# How to filter the PDAs based on the values present in the PDA?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

Consider this is how I am defining your state in your anchor program

```
#[account]
pub UserAccount {
    // config
    pub config: Pubkey,
    // owner
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    ...
}
```

How can I get only those PDAs with a given value config and a given value of owner?

Answer (score 6):

Consider this is how you are defining your state in your anchor program

```
#[account]
pub UserAccount {
    // config
    pub config: Pubkey, // config starts form an offset of 8 as 8 bytes is used for anchor's discriminator
    // owner
    pub owner: Pubkey, // owner starts from an offset of 40 as 8 bytes is used for anchor's discriminator + 32 bytes is used by config
    ...
}
```

This is how you will filter the PDAs based on the values present in the PDA

```
const pdas = await anchorProgram.account.userAccount.all([
  {
    memcmp: {
      // offset is the number of bytes from which the value is starting
      offset: 8, //need to prepend 8 bytes for anchor's disc
      bytes: config.toBase58(),
    },
  },
  {
    memcmp: {
      // offset is the number of bytes from which the value is starting
      offset: 40, //need to prepend 8 bytes for anchor's disc
      bytes: owner.toBase58(),
    },
  },
]);
```